# "vagrant up" failing: Vagrant VM failed to remain in the running state

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

The command `vagrant up` is failing and I don't know why.

```
$ egrep -v '^ *(#|$)' Vagrantfile
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
end
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'precise32'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
The VM failed to remain in the "running" state while attempting to boot.
This is normally caused by a misconfiguration or host system incompatibilities.
Please open the VirtualBox GUI and attempt to boot the virtual machine
manually to get a more informative error message.
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

default                   poweroff (virtualbox)

The VM is powered off. To restart the VM, simply run `vagrant up`
$ VBoxManage list runningvms
$
```

Here are the messages in the VirtualBox log file, VBoxSVC.log:

```
$ cat ~/.VirtualBox/VBoxSVC.log
VirtualBox XPCOM Server 4.2.16 r86992 linux.amd64 (Jul  4 2013 16:29:59) release log
00:00:00.000499 main     Log opened 2013-08-13T18:40:45.907580000Z
00:00:00.000508 main     OS Product: Linux
00:00:00.000509 main     OS Release: 3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64
00:00:00.000510 main     OS Version: #1 SMP Tue Jan 8 20:57:42 UTC 2013
00:00:00.000537 main     DMI Product Name: X8DA3
00:00:00.000547 main     DMI Product Version: 1234567890
00:00:00.000647 main     Host RAM: 24103MB total, 17127MB available
00:00:00.000654 main     Executable: /usr/local/VirtualBox/VBoxSVC
00:00:00.000655 main     Process ID: 9417
00:00:00.000656 main     Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.110125 nspr-2   Loading settings file "/opt/tomcat/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml"     with version "1.12-linux"
00:00:00.110817 nspr-2   Failed to retrive disk info: getDiskName(/dev/md126p1) --> md126p1
00:00:00.264367 nspr-2   VDInit finished
00:00:00.275173 nspr-2   Loading settings file "/opt/tomcat/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_getting_started_default_1376419129/vagrant_getting_started_default_1376419129.vbox" with version "1.12-linux"
00:00:05.288923 main     ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c) aIID={29989373-b111-4654-8493-2e1176cba890} aComponent={Medium} aText={Medium '/opt/tomcat/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_getting_started_default_1376419129/box-disk1.vmdk' cannot be closed because it is still attached to 1 virtual machines}, preserve=false
00:00:05.290229 Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={3b2f08eb-b810-4715-bee0-bb06b9880ad2} aComponent={VirtualBox} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false
$
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to boot the VM manually from VirtualBox GUI as suggested? From error message it seems that it can't access disk image.

Comment: I tried the VirtualBox GUI, but it didn't present any clearer information.

Comment: Have you tried to enable debug by `VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up`? This should output something useful. BTW: make sure you use latest vagrant, which is 1.2.7 now.

Comment: Terry, yes, I tried VAGRANT_LOG=info... The problem isn't with Vagrant; it's with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same error on OSX. Restarting VirtualBox fixed it :S

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

Also see: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=5489

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by re-installing VirtualBox and adding myself to the `vboxusers` group. The re-installation process printed a message indicating that VM users had to be a member of that group. I don't know if the re-installation was necessary or if being added to the group would have sufficed.

Comment: For me a restart was sufficient see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The host machine was 32bits (Ubuntu) and the guest was 64bit, I changed the guest to 32 and it solved the problem.

Comment: That was exactly my problem.

Comment: 1+ That was the root of the problem

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that vboxusers group is related to accessing USB devices within the guest. Not sure why it is causing the issue. **Normally, as a vagrant base box build guideline, audio and USB are both disabled.**

As per the VirtualBox Manual => [The vboxusers group](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idp10857536)

The Linux installers create the system user group `vboxusers` during installation. Any system user who is going to use USB devices from VirtualBox guests must be a member of that group. A user can be made a member of the group vboxusers through the GUI user/group management or at the command line with `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username`

> Note that adding an active user to that group will require that user to log out and back in again. This should be done manually after successful installation of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It is because I did a wrong configuration on my Vagrantfile in the provider section. I had tried to make my VM machine more powerfull, with 2 cpus when i have on the machine host just one. 
this often happens when you try to add more hardware to your VM machine but your host machine does not have the minimun requirements

Comment: I configured a minimum VM with only 1 CPU. Reinstalling VirtualBox fixed the problem.